# Reset CDMA USB Modem without unplug/replug

Tags: usb, reset, wvdial, cdma

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you reset a USB device from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line)

I have CE682 USB Modem connected using wvdial.

Every time it got disconnected, i cant reconnect without unplug and replug. If i execute wvdial without replug, it will only throw meaningless junk in the terminal as shown here:

[image]

**How do I reset the USB modem without having to unplug each time it got disconnected?**

Comment: Thank You @TomBrossman even tho my modem is not a camera i tried your suggestion:

Downloaded Li Lio's script and do usb reset:
$lsusb
Bus 002 Device 033: ID 201e:1022
$sudo ./usbreset /dev/bus/usb/002/033
Resetting USB device /dev/bus/usb/002/033
Reset successful
$sudo wvdial smart
result:
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT#777
OK
and hang until i pressed ctrl-c

IF i waited quite long before typing wvdial smart, it got the carrier, but with this as the result:

--> Disconnecting at Mon Oct  1 10:31:34 2012
--> The PPP daemon has died: Loopback detected (exit code = 17)

Comment: also tried sskolow's tip, it was fruitless, only get an increasing device number in lsusb. But the modem is not recognized by wvdial, even after modprobe.