# Startup script to unmount and re-mount a USB device

Tags: wireless, mouse, scripts, scrolling, unmount

I have a Microsoft wireless mouse and it has a scrolling issue in Ubuntu. The scrolling is too sensitive. I've read in other threads that the solution to this is unplugging the USB receiver of the mouse and then plugging it back. This indeed works but is a very uncomfortable solutions.

My question is:
Is there a script I could run on startup to unmount the USB and mount it back, and if so how would I do something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to reset USB device?

Source: http://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line