# USB ports will not recognize flash drive

Tags: usb, flash, drive

I have a little problem with a customer's Ubuntu.

USB ports won't work, but if I restart the computer, the light on the flash drive starts blinking and I can mount the flash drive.

As you can see here:

```
guest-HFuyrW@liv-Aspire-1810TZ:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298,1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    12G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   3,9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda6   8:6    0 158,3G  0 part 
└─sda7   8:7    0 123,9G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1   496M  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   496M  0 part
```

now the drive is flashing, still unmounted, but flashing. atleast it got power now.

but when i take it out and plugg it back in it shows:

```
guest-HFuyrW@liv-Aspire-1810TZ:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298,1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    12G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   3,9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda6   8:6    0 158,3G  0 part 
└─sda7   8:7    0 123,9G  0 part /
```

get what I mean now? and I don't know how to get it working, that's where the help is needed. I can't turn the computer off and on again every time I plug a drive in

I'm not used to Ubuntu or Linux.

Comment: see if this helps http://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line/290519#290519

Comment: also: using debian, I had to install `usbmount`, but sometimes automout apps will conflict with `mountall` which is installed in ubuntu by default. To check to see if mountall is installed, run: `dpkg -l | grep mount` and see if it is listed. If listed, it's installed. They may not conflict but might, i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can try unplugging and plugging the device back in.

Also, i've noticed sometimes the device doesn't mount until I click on the device in thunar (or nautilus). First, open the file manager (nautilus, thunar, whatever) and click on the device icon down on the left to mount the device.

To manually mount a device, open a terminal and type the following commands:

First, list all devices:

```
lsblk
```

here's an example of the output

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 223.4G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   9.5G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1   3.7G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   3.6G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   1   1.9G  0 disk /media/myawesomeusername/8817-272B
sr0     11:0    1     2K  0 rom
```

In this example, we have the hard drive at /dev/sda, an unmounted USB drive at /dev/sdb and a mounted USB drive at /dev/sdc.

To mount the unmounted USB drive at /mnt, we would run the following command:

```
sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

The contents of the drive should now be available in the folder /mnt.

To explain mount mounts the drive, -o rw is for the option read write, /dev/sdb1 is the usb partition we want to mount, and /mnt is the mount point where the contents of the drive will display.

To unmount the drive, either click the eject button or run the following command:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Thing is when i plugg the usb out it will not turn back on, if you get what i mean? not even the light will turn on on the flash drive, but when i restart the computer it turns on again..

Comment: Yes, just plugging the device back in doesn't necessarily mount the device. Is the device listed when you run `lsblk`?

Comment: no, the will not show in there either, i have to restart the laptop then it comes back

Comment: ahhhh, try running `lsusb` first and then check again to see if that made the system recognize the device.

Comment: i did when i had the stick flashing, then it found it. when i took it out and plugged it back in, it was gone :(

Comment: @Mortyy also, don't expect the light to flash until the device is mounted, not when it is recognized.