# What is the Equivalent Command to Ubuntu's GUI "Mount"?

Tags: command-line, usb, 16.04, mount

Situation: Ubuntu-mount USB drive on the system by a terminal command, same as Ubuntu's GUI mount
Configurations

```
# http://askubuntu.com/q/648159/25388
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false
```

- Command `ls /media/masi` gives blank.
- You see the disk icon in the panel. If you click it, the file-manager opens. Now, you can `ls /media/masi` and you see the disk.

My unsuccessful script

```
USER="masi"
LABEL="MasiWeek" # https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297425/16920
PARTION="sdb" #$(basename $(readlink $LABEL))
sudo mkdir -p /media/"$USER"/"$LABEL"
sudo mount /dev/"$PARTITION" /media/"$USER"/"$LABEL"
```

- Output

  ```
  mount:  /dev is not a block device
  ```

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
Related: [Find kernel name for a partition when only the label is known](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297425/16920)

Answer (score 7):

Your script is not working because of a spelling error in the definition of `PARTITION`.

Because of this, `PARTITION` is empty (while `PARTION` contains what you want) and `/dev/$PARTITION` becomes `/dev/`.

Note that the variable `$USER` already contains the username, so no need to set it (unless you want to do the mounting from a different user).

Comment: This is not what I mean by *Ubuntu's mount*. It is the GUI mount, not the terminal `mount` explicitly.

Comment: To get exactly the same thing as ubuntu's mount, see @steeldriver's answer. This was just to point out the flaw in your script (which should work with that fix, but require sudo privileges, in contrast to gvfs-mount)

Comment: What do you think about `mount -L MasiWeek /media/masi/MasiWeek`? I cannot think that Ubuntu's mount works without `label`.

Comment: But again, the GUI mounting does not need any additional privileges, so it cannot be the normal `mount`, which does.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way for it.

Comment: It does not have to do it in one command, though. Maybe it gets the label of the drive via `blkid /dev/sdb1`, creates the mountpoint if necessary with that label and then uses `gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdb1` or similar to mount it. But I'm really just guessing here.

Answer (score 5):

The equivalent to the Ubuntu GUI's mount action for removable media would be

```
gvfs-mount -d device
```

or

```
gvfs-mount --device=device
```

where *device* is a block device such as `/dev/sdb`. Note that this command is executed as the owner of the current desktop session, and will mount the device into a directory such as `/media/<user>/<label>` rather than to a system-wide mount point like `/mnt/<label>`. For example, mounting a USB stick:

```
$ gvfs-mount --device=/dev/sdb
Mounted /dev/sdb at /media/steeldriver/KINGSTON
```

---

To determine the block device to use in the `gvfs-mount` command, you could use `blkid` however the cache may not accurately reflect removable devices, so you'd need to run

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null
```

which clears the cache before enumerating the devices - but that requires administrative privileges. For a non-privileged method, you could examine the output of `gvfs-mount --list --detail` for a string identifying the volume - such as

```
Drive(2): Kingston DT Elite 3.0
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
  ids:
   unix-device: '/dev/sdb'
```

To unmount, you can use `gvfs-mount -u` or `gvfs-mount --unmount` e.g.

```
gvfs-mount --unmount /media/steeldriver/KINGSTON
```

Comment: The advantage of `gvfs-mount` over `mount` is that the former does not need `sudo` rights, correct?

Comment: @cas says to use `mount -L MasiWeek /media/masi/MasiWeek` where label and UUID. Is it the same as `gvfs-mount --device=/media/masi/MasiWeek`? There is no `label` option in `gvfs-mount`.

Comment: @Masi AFAIK the `--device` option of `gvfs-mount` only takes a block device argument - I've never tried it with a label.

Comment: @steeldriver There is no `label` in `gvfs-mount`. What do you mean by a *block device argument*?

Answer (score 0):

@cas' [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297425/16920) in comments is more strict than `gvfs-mount` because it has also `label` option, thus avoiding possible complications better; I think Ubuntu use's the label option for stability so I doubt if `gvfs-mount --mount` is used at all by default

```
mount -L MasiWeek /media/masi/MasiWeek
```