# How can I reset usb port after over current draw?

Tags: usb, power-management, devices

I am powering my Raspbery pi with my USB2 port on my ubuntu laptop. Periodically, the USB power goes into over current protection and shuts down the port. I can reboot, and the port gets re-enabled, but that is troublesome.

How can I reset the USB port, without having to reboot?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't a function of the OS, which means that doing something in Ubuntu probably won't reset it.

Comment: Im pretty sure the OS can control the hardware, if I know how to give it the right signals.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you reset a USB device from the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line)

Comment: It is probably slightly crude to point to an article from five years ago, but if that one helps you (and even if it doesn't), please add your experiences to that answer. We like to keep all the information about a certain issue in one place.