# How to Reset a USB device after improper shutdown(device no longer visible) without unplugging

Tags: command-line, usb

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and am running the Realsense D435 sensor through a USB3 port. Unfortunately when the device is not shut down properly it disappears from the USB list and does not reappear unless I unplug and re-insert. I am trying to figure out how to reset this without unplugging.

I found the links below , but it seems like all of those need the device to be present on the `lsusb` list.

[How to reconnect a logically disconnected USB device | Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7412/how-to-reconnect-a-logically-disconnected-usb-device)

[How do you reset a USB device from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line)

I also tried the script below to unbind and re-bind my USB hubs:

```
echo -n "0000:00:14.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind     
echo -n "0000:00:1a.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/unbind  
echo -n "0000:00:1d.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/unbind  
sleep 5s                  
echo -n "0000:00:1d.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/bind  
echo -n "0000:00:1a.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/bind   
echo -n "0000:00:14.0" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
```

This script 100% kills power to all devices connected, i.e. keyboard, mouse, Bluetooth dongle, so I think it does cut the power, but unfortunately the Realsense D435 sensor does not re-appear!

Nothing short of unplugging (or shutdown > kill power > restart PC) helps. Any suggestions?