# USB FlashDrive - Reconnecting every 5 seconds

Tags: boot, usb

I run Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on my laptop and I have difficulties using my Kingston USB Flash drive - as it will disconnect and then reconnect constantly in an infinite loop unless taken out of the port manually.

Before submitting this question - I have applied whatever I could see fit discussed in a similiar fashion below:

- [How do you reset a USB device from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line)
- https://www.linux.org/threads/resetting-the-usb-subsystem.10404/

Nothing seems to work for me unfortunately, I really hope that there is a solution other than trowing the thing away.

Interestingly Using a USB3 adapter to USB 3.2 Gen 2 Type-C, I managed to use an exernal SSD and that problem is not occuring with this setup, although that it is rather impractical.

Kind regards,

Comment: Try different ports and whether the issue repeats on other computers. If yes, throw away, if no then it may be related to your computer, but then it would be expected to occur with other USB's as well.

Comment: @vanadium Thanks, but the USB works well on Windows OS just fine, so perhaps it has to do with how Linux operates with the USB Bus and interface I guess. Strange thing is, that it started happening right away when I plugged that in.